Modifying Angular 16 mat-form-field styles
I am looking to change the default styling of Angular Material's MatFormField. I want to reduce the inner padding of the input field in a form field, and reduce the gap between each form field.
I am aware that I probably need to modify some of the css styles Angular puts on the component but I have no idea what needs to be changed exactly.
Example of how I currently use the form fields (I want to reduce the gap between each form field and reduce the padding in the input fields)
<mat-form-field class="col-span-12">
            <input 
            type="text"
            matInput
            ngModel
            (input)="filter(selectedLayer.value)"
            name="select"
            #selectedLayer="ngModel"
            [matAutocomplete]="auto">
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" (optionSelected)="onSelectedOption($event)">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions" [value]="option">
                        {{ option.label }}
                    </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field class="col-span-4">
            <input
            #fieldInput="ngModel"
            type="text"
            matInput
            disabled
            ngModel
            name="field">
</mat-form-field>

I was looking to override the styles of the form fields in the css but it didn't really work, bascially nothing changed in the visualization.
I am starting to think if I should create my own components and just extend the material ones?

you can try applying CSS to it like setting its width and font size.
for example:
mat-form-field{
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 12px;
  }

just check if this is the thing you want or maybe i'm wrong
or else can you provide me the code like its html and ts file if possible.

You can use the host selector of the element from the official Angular Material 16 to change the appearance of the input element.
.mat-mdc-form-field input {
 padding: insertYourValue;
}

https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api#material-form-field-testing-classes
